# Recursive function to get some column value of parent using python/pyspark/pandas/GraphX

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, spark-graphx

I have a dataframe containing item_id,parent_id,type and label as :

| item_id | parent_id | type | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d71 | f5f | list | item list |
| 2009 | 911 | question | 2.1 item question |
| 738 | NULL | section | item section |
| 911 | 738 | category | 2. item category |
| f5f | 2009 | smartfield | NULL |

I want output as

| item_id | parent_id | type | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d71 | f5f | list | 2. item category |
| 2009 | 911 | question | 2. item category |
| 738 | NULL | section | item section |
| 911 | 738 | category | 2. item category |
| f5f | 2009 | smartfield | 2. item category |

What I need is to traverse the item_id till its parent_id until type = category, get the label of this item_id's type and have its label value in all of the item_id except if item_id's type = section. This is just an example, but I dont know the depth level of the item.

Comment: Can you format input and output properly?

Comment: Edited the post.